# Markov Chain reaching an absorbing state after hitting a certain state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm stucked in this markov chain problem. 
I need to know the probability of reaching the absorbing state "C" right after hitting the state "B" and starting at the state "A". The matrix transition is:

```
     A     B      C
    0.79  0.2    0.01   A
    0.7   0.28   0.02   B
     0     0      1     C
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hint: Possible ways of doing this: $$ABC, ABABC, ABABABC, \dots$$You can work out these probabilities and sum them, giving a geometric sum

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that, but I can't come up with a way of compiling every possible sequence ...

Comment: But, it isn't that simple as going from A to B everytime right? it can do "AAABBBABABAAC" and there is a lot of probabilities inside that path, right?

Comment: Ahh yes you're right, my comment above misses a lot of cases. See my alternative method in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the probability of reaching $C$ starting from the point $i$ and going through $B$ by $p_i$. Then we have the two equations $$p_A=0.2p_B+0.79p_A\\p_B=0.02+0.7p_A+0.28 p_B$$
Solve these to find $p_A$, which is what they ask for.

---

How did we get these equations?

The first equation says the way to reach your target, starting at $A$ is by either first going to $B$ then figuring out how to reach the target from there, or by going straight back to $A$, and figuring out how to reach the target from there.

The second equation says the way to reach your target starting at $B$ is by either going straight to $C$ (which is your target, so you're done), or by going to $A$ then figuring out how to get to your target from there, or by going to $B$ then figuring out how to get to your target from there.

This is a common method used for solving problems like this (Markov processes).

Comment: Thanks man! Can you elaborate a bit? or quote me any source about this kind of problems? I'm struggling to understand it

Comment: @Yogesh I elaborated on how we reached these equations. Do you have any other specific questions? Such as what you don't particularly understand?

Comment: Oooh. Yeah!! I completely get it now man. Thank you so much.

PS: I can't upvote your answer due to have less than 15 reputation, but feel upvoted!

Comment: No problem! ${}$

Comment: Hey John. It's not intuitive to me why to compute $p_i$ we are conditioning on the next state that it can reach. Typically, don't we condition on the state that reaches state $i$?

Comment: @David with Markov chains we look at the probabilities as one-step processes, so stuff like $\Bbb P(X_1=x_1|X_0=x_0)$. So we're computing the probability of going to some state ($x_1$) given that we are already at some other state ($x_0$). In this question we were looking at the probability of going along some path which ends with a jump from B to C. $p_i$ is just this - the probability of reaching C by going through B, having started at $i$. If we set $i=A$, the first equation naturally follows, but has a $p_B$ term in it, so we need the second equation to solve the problem. Make more sense?

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh I misunderstood $p_i$. It was defined to be the probability of getting to point $C$ from point $i$. I thought it was the probability of getting to point $i$. Does it make sense to ask the question "what is the marginal probability of getting to point $i$, given nothing (i.e., given no starting state)?

Comment: @David Since C is an absorbing state, and there are no other absorbing states / loops in this problem, it is true that eventually the system will hit C - the probability of never hitting C in infinitely many steps tends to 0. It would however make sense to ask what the expected number of steps is to hit C for each of the possible starting points - see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Examples) example for a similar problem. Alternatively you could also perhaps ask what the probability of being at state i is at any given time. Then, $\lim_{t\to\infty}(P(X_t=i))=1$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh right. My question actually didn't make sense now that I think about it. I think I meant if it made sense to ask "what is the marginal probability of getting to point i, in a given number of time steps"

Comment: @David So you could try to work that out given each starting state, then compute a weighted sum of these, with the weights signifying the probability of starting at each state (this is necessary). Explicitly, you would assume that you randomly start at one of states A,B,C with probabilities $q_A,q_B,q_C$ (e.g. $q_A=q_B=q_C=\frac13$). Denote $p_j(t)=P(X_t=i|X_0=j)$. Then the probability of being at state $i$ at some time $T$ is $P(X_T=i)=q_Ap_A(T)+q_Bp_B(T)+q_Bp_B(T)$.